# Code after startDrag() do not execute

Tags: android, drag-and-drop

What I'm trying to do is to have 4 ImageButtons on a view, then when I drag one button to the other, a message is gonna be printed in the Logcat. The thing is that even the Drag event went through START, ENTERED, LOCATION, EXITED, DROP, ENDED with no problem, but the rest of onLongClick(), the code after v.startDrag() does not work.
Thanks in advanced.

```
public class HomeAcitivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener, OnLongClickListener 
    {
    //int windowWidth = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getWidth();
    //int windowHeight = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getHeight();

    public static int action = 0; // what action to take:
                                    // 0: nothing
                                    // 1: song to album
                                    // 2: song to genre
                                    // 3: song to artist

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);
        initialization(savedInstanceState);
    }

    public void initialization(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        ImageButton songsMap = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.songsmap);
        songsMap.setContentDescription("none");
        songsMap.setOnClickListener(this);
        songsMap.setOnLongClickListener(this);
        ImageButton albumsMap = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.albumsmap);
        albumsMap.setContentDescription("none");
        albumsMap.setOnClickListener(this);
        albumsMap.setOnLongClickListener(this);
        ImageButton artistsMap = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.artistsmap);
        artistsMap.setOnClickListener(this);
        artistsMap.setOnLongClickListener(this);
        ImageButton genresMap = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.genresmap);
        genresMap.setOnClickListener(this);
        genresMap.setOnLongClickListener(this);
        myDragEventListener mAlbumDragListener = new myDragEventListener();
        albumsMap.setOnDragListener(mAlbumDragListener);
        myDragEventListener mSongDragListener = new myDragEventListener();
        songsMap.setOnDragListener(mSongDragListener);
        myDragEventListener mArtistDragListener = new myDragEventListener();
        artistsMap.setOnDragListener(mArtistDragListener);
        myDragEventListener mGenreDragListener = new myDragEventListener();
        genresMap.setOnDragListener(mGenreDragListener);


    }

    public boolean songtoalbum()
    {
        Log.d("Song to album:", "true");
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_home, menu);
        return true;
    }

    public void onClick(View arg0) 
    {


    }


    public boolean onLongClick(View v) 
    {
        if (v.getId() == R.id.musicmapparent)
        {
            // here modify wallpaper
            return true;
        }
        // Drag and drop
        ClipData.Item item = new ClipData.Item((CharSequence) v.getTag());
        // this part is different from the android dev:
        String[] mimetype = new String[1];
        mimetype[0] = ClipDescription.MIMETYPE_TEXT_PLAIN;

        ClipData dragData = new ClipData((CharSequence) v.getTag(), 
                                        mimetype, 
                                        item);
        View.DragShadowBuilder myShadow;

        switch(v.getId())
        {
        case R.id.albumsmap:
            myShadow = 
                new MyDragShadowBuilder (v, getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_launcher));        
                break;
        case R.id.songsmap:
            myShadow = 
                new MyDragShadowBuilder (v, getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_launcher));

            break;
        case R.id.artistsmap:
            myShadow = 
                new MyDragShadowBuilder (v, getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_launcher));

            break;
        case R.id.genresmap:
            myShadow = 
                new MyDragShadowBuilder (v, getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_launcher));
            break;
        default:
            myShadow = null;
        }

        //---------------------------------------------------------------------------

        //v.setOnDragListener(mDragListener);
        v.startDrag(dragData,  // the data to be dragged
                myShadow,  // the drag shadow builder
                null,      // no need to use local data
                0          // flags (not currently used, set to 0)
                );

        // Stuck here >"<
        Log.d("Out of Drag", "At least we get here");
        switch (HomeAcitivity.action)
        {
        case 0:
            break;
        case 1:
            Log.d("ACTION: ", "Song to album");

            //songtoalbum();

            break;
        case 2:
            Log.d("ACTION: ", "Song to genre");
            //songtogenre();
            break;
        case 3:
            Log.d("ACTION: ", "Song to artist");
            //songtoartist();
            break;
        default:
            Log.d("ACTION", "nothing");
            break;

        }
        return true;

    }

}


// To create the shadow for the object
class MyDragShadowBuilder extends View.DragShadowBuilder {

    // The drag shadow image, defined as a drawable thing
    private static Drawable shadow;

        // Defines the constructor for myDragShadowBuilder
        public MyDragShadowBuilder(View v, Drawable drawable) {
            super(v);
            shadow = drawable;
        }

        // Defines a callback that sends the drag shadow dimensions and touch point back to the
        // system.
        @Override
        public void onProvideShadowMetrics (Point size, Point touch)
        {
            // Defines local variables
            int width, height;

            // Sets the width of the shadow to half the width of the original View

            width = getView().getWidth();

            // Sets the height of the shadow to half the height of the original View
            height = getView().getHeight();

            // The drag shadow is a ColorDrawable. This sets its dimensions to be the same as the
            // Canvas that the system will provide. As a result, the drag shadow will fill the
            // Canvas.
            shadow.setBounds(0, 0, width, height);

            // Sets the size parameter's width and height values. These get back to the system
            // through the size parameter.
            size.set(width, height);

            // Sets the touch point's position to be in the middle of the drag shadow
            touch.set(width / 2, height / 2);
        }

        // Defines a callback that draws the drag shadow in a Canvas that the system constructs
        // from the dimensions passed in onProvideShadowMetrics().
        @Override
        public void onDrawShadow(Canvas canvas) {

            // Draws the ColorDrawable in the Canvas passed in from the system.
            shadow.draw(canvas);
        }
    }

class myDragEventListener implements OnDragListener {
    // This is the method that the system calls when it dispatches a drag event to the
    // listener.
    public boolean onDrag(View v, DragEvent event) {

        // Defines a variable to store the action type for the incoming event
        final int action = event.getAction();

        // Handles each of the expected events
        CharSequence dragData = null;
        switch(action) {

            case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_STARTED:

                // Determines if this View can accept the dragged data
                if (event.getClipDescription().hasMimeType(ClipDescription.MIMETYPE_TEXT_PLAIN)) {
                    switch(v.getId())
                    {
                    case R.id.albumsmap:

                        break;
                    case R.id.songsmap:
                        v.setContentDescription("songstart");
                        break;

                    case R.id.artistsmap:

                        break;

                    case R.id.genresmap:

                        break;

                    }
                    // As an example of what your application might do,
                    // applies a blue color tint to the View to indicate that it can accept
                    // data.
                    ((ImageView) v).setColorFilter(Color.BLUE);

                    // Invalidate the view to force a redraw in the new tint
                    v.invalidate();
                    dragData = (CharSequence) v.getTag();
                    // returns true to indicate that the View can accept the dragged data.
                    return(true);

                    } else {

                    // Returns false. During the current drag and drop operation, this View will
                    // not receive events again until ACTION_DRAG_ENDED is sent.
                    return(false);

                    }
                //break;

            case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_ENTERED:

                // Applies a green tint to the View. Return true; the return value is ignored.

                ((ImageView) v).setColorFilter(Color.GREEN);

                // Invalidate the view to force a redraw in the new tint
                v.invalidate();

                return(true);

                //break;

            case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_LOCATION:

                //
                switch(v.getId())
                {
                case R.id.albumsmap:
                    ((ImageView) v).setColorFilter(Color.RED);
                    break;
                case R.id.songsmap:
                    ((ImageView) v).setColorFilter(Color.YELLOW);
                    break;

                case R.id.artistsmap:
                    ((ImageView) v).setColorFilter(Color.WHITE);
                    break;

                case R.id.genresmap:
                    ((ImageView) v).setColorFilter(Color.BLACK);
                    break;

                }
                return(true);

                //break;

                case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_EXITED:

                    // Re-sets the color tint to blue. Returns true; the return value is ignored.
                    ((ImageView) v).setColorFilter(Color.BLUE);

                    // Invalidate the view to force a redraw in the new tint
                    v.invalidate();

                    return(true);

                //break;

                case DragEvent.ACTION_DROP:

                    // Gets the item containing the dragged data
                    ClipData.Item item = event.getClipData().getItemAt(0);

                    // Gets the text data from the item.
                    dragData = item.getText();
                    Log.d("DRAGDATA = ", (String) dragData);
                    Log.d("V.ID = ", Integer.toString(v.getId()));

                    Log.d("Album.ID = ", Integer.toString(R.id.albumsmap));
                    // Displays a message containing the dragged data.
                    //Toast.makeText(this, "Dragged data is " + dragData, Toast.LENGTH_LONG);

                    // Turns off any color tints
                    ((ImageView) v).clearColorFilter();

                    // Invalidates the view to force a redraw
                    v.invalidate();
                    String dragDataString = (String) dragData;
                    Log.d(dragDataString, dragDataString);
                    //
                    switch(v.getId())
                    {
                    case R.id.albumsmap:
                        ((ImageView) v).setColorFilter(Color.RED);

                        if (dragDataString.equals("SONG_MAP_BUTTON"))
                        {
                            HomeAcitivity.action = 1;
                            v.invalidate();

                        }
                        break;
                    case R.id.songsmap:
                        ((ImageView) v).setColorFilter(Color.YELLOW);
                        break;

                    case R.id.artistsmap:
                        if (dragDataString.equals("SONG_MAP_BUTTON"))
                        {
                            HomeAcitivity.action = 3;
                            Log.d("TAG: ", "This should be song to artist map");
                            v.invalidate();
                        }

                        break;

                    case R.id.genresmap:
                        if (dragDataString.equals("SONG_MAP_BUTTON"))
                        {
                            HomeAcitivity.action = 2;
                            Log.d("TAG: ", "This should be song to genre map");
                            v.invalidate();
                        }
                        break;

                    }


                    // Returns true. DragEvent.getResult() will return true.
                    return(true);

                //break;

                case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_ENDED:

                    // Turns off any color tinting
                    ((ImageView) v).clearColorFilter();

                    // Invalidates the view to force a redraw
                    v.invalidate();

                    // Does a getResult(), and displays what happened.
                    if (event.getResult()) {
                        Log.d("End: ", "Well, end" + v.getId());
                        //Toast.makeText(this, "The drop was handled.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);

                    } else {
                        //Toast.makeText(this, "The drop didn't work.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);

                    };

                    // returns true; the value is ignored.
                    return(true);

                //break;

                // An unknown action type was received.
                default:
                    Log.e("DragDrop Example","Unknown action type received by OnDragListener.");

                break;
        };
        return true;
    };

};
```

Comment: I think that after startDrag() it quits the OnLongClick(), any idea how to fix it?
I added 
    if (v.startDrag(...)){ // the switch - case block}
but 1st time I long click, nothing happens, the second time I do so, the result of the last long click is displayed.

Comment: Did you ever figure out your problem?